# Can I still make updates to my entity values via API call even if the Google Action is live?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Is it possible to add/remove entity values via Entity API call if the google action is live?

Based on this documentation: https://developers.google.com/actions/console/publishing#resubmission, I need to resubmit the action if "You are using Dialogflow and made changes to your Dialogflow agent. This does not apply if you only made changes to the fulfillment code in Dialogflow's inline editor." This is kind of unclear to me. Does this include any changes done using the Entity API?

I am thinking of following this tutorial: https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/entity-api/ to regularly (as in daily) update my entity values even after the action has already gone live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but...

The answer is complicated. Yes, you can update your Entity values over time, even once you are in production. And depending on the exact values, they might get picked up by Dialogflow and handed off to you.

The problem is that the Assistant might not correctly pick up on what the words are as part of its speech-to-text processing, so may not hand the right word over. This "text shaping" aspect is only updated when you resubmit/release a new version.

So *if* Dialogflow gets the words - then it will be handled correctly. But there is no guarantee this will happen.

You should setup a way to catch responses that may not match - these would be done through a Fallback Intent or through an Intent with a lower priority, but not using the Entity. You can still try to lookup the name provided this way - the Assistant may provide the name correctly, tho it would usually be caught by Dialogflow in these cases.

You probably shouldn't have much problem resubmitting relatively frequently (although daily is probably overdoing it). If you've been approved before, updates are usually approved fairly quickly, and particularly if you include in the notes what the differences are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I really appreciate it. 

The entity values that I need to regularly update are names of people. These names are updated regularly (added/deleted). The correct detection of names are essential to the google action that I'm thinking of creating since it will involve searching for people in a database. Can you give any suggestion or workarounds without me having to resubmit the action every time a change has been made? Or do you think if I only edit the entity values of the action it would be approved faster if I opt to submit for certification regularly?

Comment: I've updated the answer to, hopefully, talk a bit more about how you can work with this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it.